# SSIS expression picking up variable as column then throwing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I have a list of staff members that I aggregate into a string.
I want to feed the output of this string into an SSIS expression that I can then use as an sql statement.

Variable created is `@User::USER`

Problem is, it converts the variable to the variable name and then looks for that column.

SSIS expression is:

```
"SELECT
    CONCAT(RTRIM(USER_GIVEN_NAME), ' ', RTRIM(USER_SURNAME)) as [User]
    ,user_num
FROM [dbo].[USER_B]
where CONCAT(RTRIM(USER_GIVEN_NAME), ' ', RTRIM(USER_SURNAME)) in (" +  @[User::USERS] + ")"
```

Variable is set to evaluate as expression.

This then evaluates to:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(RTRIM(USER_GIVEN_NAME), ' ', RTRIM(USER_SURNAME)) as [User]
    ,user_num
FROM [dbo].[USER_B]
where CONCAT(RTRIM(USER_GIVEN_NAME), ' ', RTRIM(USER_SURNAME)) in (USERS)

@user::USERS = 'xxx','yyy','zzz'
```

I'm sure it's a syntax error or settings error but am yet to resolve this.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Get the list of users:

```
SELECT
    STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(CONCAT(USER_GIVEN_NAME, ' ', USER_SURNAME),''''), ',') as USERS
FROM [Operations Stats].[dbo].[Team Members]

;

"SELECT
    CONCAT(RTRIM(USER_GIVEN_NAME), ' ', RTRIM(USER_SURNAME)) as [User]
    ,user_num
FROM [dbo].[USER_B]
where CONCAT(RTRIM(USER_GIVEN_NAME), ' ', RTRIM(USER_SURNAME)) in (" +  @[User::USERS] + ")"
```

I would like the `@user::USER` to evaluate to the `'xxx','yyy','zzz'` and not think of it as `USER` column.

Comment: Your `@[User:USERS]` variable shouldn't be an expression - it should simply contain the string you composed with `STRING_AGG`. If you switched on *evaluate as expression* to get rid of the issue of your variable being undefinded, simply put an empty string `""` as the default value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as @Filburt mentioned in the comment above, make sure that you didn't set `Evaluate As Expression` to `@[User:USERS]` variable.

I will suggest another method to do that, Create a variable of type string `@[User::strQuery]` and before the data flow task add an expression task with the following expression:

```
@[User:strQuery] = "SELECT
CONCAT(RTRIM(USER_GIVEN_NAME), ' ', RTRIM(USER_SURNAME)) as [User]
,user_num
FROM [dbo].[USER_B]
where CONCAT(RTRIM(USER_GIVEN_NAME), ' ', RTRIM(USER_SURNAME)) in (" +  @[User::USERS] + ")"
```

And click on the Data Flow Task and set the `Delay Validation` property to `True`.

I think that using Expression Task is more precise and you will be aware of changing variables properties.